# Instance an object in an array which is an attribute of antoher object

Tags: arrays, object, attributes, java

What is the correct way of declaring an instance of an object which is part of an array that is an attribute of another object? I have a class called *ingrediente* which is quite simple. It looks like this:

```
public class ingrediente{
public int cantidad;
public String nombre;
public int fechaDeCaducidad;}
```

I have another class called *receta* which has an array of *ingrediente* objects:

```
public class receta{
ingrediente [] ingredientes;
String preparacion;
String nombreReceta;}
```

I want to give values to the attributes of an *ingrediente* object which is part of the array ingredientes in an instance of the *receta* class. I'm not even sure if I have to declare the *ingrediente* object before giving values to it, but the code doesn't work (although it doesn't show syntax errors) wether I do it or not. The code looks like this:

```
recetas [CONTADORRECETAS].ingredientes [CONTADORINGREDIENTES2] = new ingrediente ();
recetas [CONTADORRECETAS].ingredientes [CONTADORINGREDIENTES2].nombre = TEMP2;
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code is inside a try and it throws java.lang.NullPointerException on those lines (on the first one if I include it and on second one if I don't). The value of the attribute doesn't get asigned. Variable TEMP2 is previously declarated and is of the correct type.

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong ?

Comment: The value doesn't get asigned. Also, the code is inside a try, and it jumps to the catch in those lines.

Comment: What is the exception being thrown ? (I already know the answer : IndexOutOfBoundException. But it's to make you see that first you do not give enough information for people to help at your own problem, second do some research, before asking, the solution if often in the error message)

Comment: I'm sorry, I try to explain it as clear as I can, but these concepts are all new to me. I don't know how to check which is the exception thrown.

Comment: In your catch clause, your should print the stackTrace of the exception (`e.printStackTrace()`) So in your console you will see the error. It will give you the type of error, the line causing it, and sometimes more info.

Comment: Here the problem is that your ingredient array is emtpy. But you try to access an item to modify it (to set it to `new ingrediente()`). But this item does not exist, the system can't access it -> error.  You need to first initialize your array with a length

Comment: Thank you very much. The exception thrown is java.lang.NullPointerException. How can I declare the array first? I'm trying with `ingrediente [] recetas [CONTADORRECETAS].ingredientes = new ingrediente [1000];` but the syntax seems incorrect.